# How to navigate to another activity when click on listitem

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to navigate one page to another in react native. Here I want to navigate to my activity to another activity, When i click on list item this will navigate to another page You can check my code below

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,  AppRegistry,} from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem, Icon, Text } from 'native-base';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Adjective        from './Topic/Adjective';

class BasicFlatList extends Component {

    onSourcesSetting = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Adj');
    }

     render(){

      return(
        <List>
            <ListItem 
            button
            noBorder
            onPress={() => this.onSourcesSetting}>
            <Text>Adjective</Text>
            </ListItem>

        </List>
        );
    }

}

const App = StackNavigator({
    Adj: Adjective, 


  });

export default BasicFlatList;
```

Comment: Refer [How to navigate from one screen to another scree in react native>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875496/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-scree-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new screen(component) and pass the name of that route and other required parameters to the function.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,  AppRegistry,} from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem, Icon, Text } from 'native-base';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Adjective        from './Topic/Adjective';

  class BasicFlatList extends Component {

    onSourcesSetting = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('AdjDetail', {
          // require params(maybe adj id)
        });
    }

     render(){

      return(
        <List>
            <ListItem 
            button
            noBorder
            onPress={() => this.onSourcesSetting}>
            <Text>Adjective</Text>
            </ListItem>

        </List>
        );
    }

}

class AdjectiveDetail extends React.Component {
 render() {
   console.log("props", this.props);
   return null;
 }
}

const App = StackNavigator({
    Adj: Adjective, 
    AdjDetail: AdjectionDetail

  });

export default BasicFlatList;
```

From the code i guess you are using react-navigation. You can go through the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/) for more details

P.S: react-native creates a single activity and entire app is run inside the single activity, there is no such thing as navigate from one activity to another like in android.